# The following subset is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that $5x+xy=0$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ since it follows the $(u+v)$ and the $c(u)$ theorem. However, is this subset always a subspace or only sometimes a subspace?

Answer (score 0):

If we define $$V=\{(x,y):5x+xy=0\}$$ then $(1,-5)$ and $(0,5)$ belong to $V$, but $(1,-5)+(0,5)=(1,0)$ does not belong to $V$ (since $5 \times 1+1 \times 0 \neq 0$).  So it's not closed under vector addition.

Alternatively, we can visualize this subset by
\begin{align*}
V &= \{(x,y):5x+xy=0\} \\
 &= \{(x,y):x(5+y)=0\} \\
 &= \{(x,y):x=0 \text{ or } y=-5\}
\end{align*}
which is the union of two distinct lines $x=0$ and $y=-5$.

Comment: ok so 5x+xy=0 is only sometimes a subset for the r2 subspace?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "sometimes" a subset.  It doesn't change over time.  It's not a subspace, and that's it.